# Does this show a defect in my Dell monitor, or is it acceptable?

Tags: display, defective-hardware

After the system powers off, my monitor (Dell 3011 2560x1600) continues to display the contents of the video buffer for a LONG time. Right now the PC has been powered off and the display cable disconnected for about 16 minutes (no exaggeration) and the monitor is *still* displaying the shutdown screen. I've pulled out the DisplayPort cable (see photo) so its definitely the monitor's buffer, not the PC or VGA card.

Every few minutes the location of the speckled part changes between a couple of places on the screen, probably related to the monitor's video ram buffer changing.

[image]
[image]
[image]
I've never seen this on any previous monitor.  Any ideas what's up and if I should seek an RMA? Does it hint at any likely future problems?

Has anyone else got experience of a monitor doing this?

Comment: There is definitely something wrong here - before yo RMA it, have you tried replacing the cable?

Comment: See 1st photo - the cable is not plugged in. This is the monitors video buffer.

Comment: Ah, sorry - that did not show clearly as a cable (I thought it was a black area of the screen) on my cellphone.

Comment: this is cool. And strange.